# org-agenda with habits overlayed with colored red colums. Why?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

Does anybody have an idea why my agenda view looks like this? 
I am running spacemacs with org-agenda using lots of habits like this:

```
**** TODO Consume a tablespoon of linen oil once per day
     SCHEDULED: <2017-06-01 Do 06:30 ++1d >
     :PROPERTIES:
     :LAST_REPEAT: [2017-06-02 Fr 09:11]
     :STYLE:    habit
     :END:
     :LOGBOOK:
     - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-06-02 Fr 09:11]
     :END:
  blablab blablab blablab blablab blablab blablab blablab blablab
```

[image: Screenshoot of the agenda view]

GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2017-05-14

Org mode version 9.0.8 (9.0.8-elpaplus )

Any hints welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that all indicated habits are overdue? See [Tracking your habits](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html#Tracking-your-habits).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That might be it. But shouldnt it be then shown the first collum of the table instead of overlaying the habit's text.? I will verify how it looks when I complete them.

Answer (score 6):

I think I'm three years too late, but I so rarely have anything to contribute to stack overflow so here goes.

The property you're looking for is `org-habit-graph-column` , it's default value is 40, and it sets the number of columns over the habit graph starts at. It will overwrite anything written beyond those first 40 columns, which is what it looks like happened. To fix this you just have to add `(setq org-habit-graph-column 80)` to your init file, with 80 as an example as a further out column distance. It may have to be even further cuz you have some pretty long habit names, but it'll solve your overwrite problem.